# Y/N: UitableView Question

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Y/N: Is it possible to set *one* cell inside of a uitableview that has *multiple* cells to have a dynamic height that changes depending on the value of text it holds?

Comment: You'll have better luck if you tag your question with the appropriate programming language and/or framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can specify the height of a cell by implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewDelegate`. You can get the row height using NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method.

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks for at least pointing me in the right direction. I'll get going on figuring out how to implement those methods. Thanks again.

Comment: Search on StackOverflow, there are a number of examples.